# Minimizing a quantity for a constant.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, quadratics, self-learning, mean-square-error

Mean squared error for an estimator is $\sigma^4\{a^2(n^2-1)-2a(n-1)+1\},$ where $n$ is the sample size and $a$ is constant. I have to show this mean squared error(mse) is minimized at $a=\frac{1}{(n+1)}.$ So, I set mse equal to $0$, that is,

$$\sigma^4\{a^2(n^2-1)-2a(n-1)+1\}=0$$
$$\Rightarrow a^2(n^2-1)-2a(n-1)+1=0$$
$$\Rightarrow a=\frac{-\{-2(n-1)\}\pm \sqrt{\{-2(n-1)\}^2-4(n^2-1)(1)}}{2(n^2-1)}$$
$$\Rightarrow a=\frac{2(n-1)\pm \sqrt{4(n-1)^2-4(n-1)(n+1)}}{2(n^2-1)}$$
$$\Rightarrow a=\frac{2(n-1)\pm \sqrt{4(n-1)\{(n-1)-(n+1)\}}}{2(n^2-1)}$$
$$\Rightarrow a=\frac{2(n-1)\pm \sqrt{4(n-1)(-2)}}{2(n^2-1)}$$

But I don't end up with the result $a=\frac{1}{(n+1)}.$ Could you please tell me where I am doing mistake?

Comment: If you want the minimum of your MSE, you'd set its derivative equal to zero. Your expression is quadratic, though; so the minimum is attained at $-b/(2a)$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you. I got the answer.

Comment: Your result involved $\sqrt{-2}$.  This shows that the mean square error is never zero.